# Is there a way to save data from users without registration in Flutter?

Tags: sql, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently building a Flutter app which lets users do personality tests, and until now I planned to do it without forcing users to register an account via Firebase (as this is annoying for many users).

Problem I am facing now is that I need the results from the tests from the users, so that I can tell the users in the result section how these results are compared to the average of all people who have done the test.

If a user would now register, the test results would be saved locally on the device. Will it then still be possible to save the test results in a online database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to force users to sign in but still need to differentiate between them, you can use [Firebase Anonymous Authentication](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#anonymous-sign-in) which will create a user account in Firebase and return a UID similar to any other auth method. A new anonymous authentication can be created by using `signInAnonymously()` method:

```dart
UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
```

As you get a unique UID for each user, you can then store data in database itself instead of storing locally. If the user proceeds with registration, you can [convert this anonymous account to a permanent account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account) using [`linkWithCredential`](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#linking-user-accounts) method. *The UID of user remains the same.*

---

Do note that if the user logs out of the anonymous account, then there is no way to retrieve that same anonymous account back.

Comment: Thx, that sounds fitting, I will try that ^^